# Scala 2.13 and Spark 3.2.1 is not running concurrently on executors

Tags: java, apache-spark

Trying to do parallel processing of list using `scala 2.13` and `spark 3.2.1`.It seems to run in single task in `local` with spark master of 4 threads `local[4]`. May be missing something here.

Below is what I am trying and the libs related to `spark` and `scala`

create a print method

```java
public static void m1(String i){
    System.out.println("===thread=="+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"===value=="+i);
}
```

`spark` code to print using `rdd`

```java
 final SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                    .appName("appName")
                    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1500)
                    .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", 1500)
                    .config("spark.master", "local[4]")
                   .getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> data = sparkSession.read().option(HEADER, TRUE).csv("path to csv");
Dataset<Row> lines = data.na().fill("");
  
JavaRDD<Row> oprdd = lines.javaRDD().map(x -> {
    try {
        m1(x.mkString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return  x;
    }
    return x;
});

oprdd.rdd().collect();
```

```
compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.13:3.2.1'
compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.13:3.2.1'
```

Below is output

```
===thread==Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5)===value==bcd
===thread==Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5)===value==efg
===thread==Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5)===value==hij
===thread==Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5)===value==klm
===thread==Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5)===value==nop
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original code was probably enough to hint at whats happening.

```java
public static void m1(int i){
System.out.println("===thread=="+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"===value=="+i);
}

// then later in a method
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("UDFExample")
        .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
        .getOrCreate();

List<Integer> ar = Arrays.asList(2,4,3,6,1,5);
JavaRDD<Integer> outputRdd1 = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(spark.sparkContext()).parallelize(ar).map(x -> {
    try {
        m1(x);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return x;
    }
    return x;
});

outputRdd1.collect().forEach( i -> System.out.println("res was "+i));
```

on a box with enough cores will give:

```
===thread==Executor task launch worker for task 13.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 13)===value==1
===thread==Executor task launch worker for task 15.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 15)===value==5
===thread==Executor task launch worker for task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5)===value==4
===thread==Executor task launch worker for task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7)===value==3
===thread==Executor task launch worker for task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)===value==2
===thread==Executor task launch worker for task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10)===value==6
res was 2
res was 4
res was 3
res was 6
res was 1
res was 5
```

and a lot of task logging, that's on OSS 3.4.1.  If you are using the Databricks runtime (as per the tag) note it is not OSS and it's free to optimize how it sees fit, in this case, and the csv file one, it could simply chosen based on size to keep it on the driver node in a single thread and save you money.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i updated my question with having spark local as master with 4  threads(local[4]) with array it divides fine, but with csv file the tasks are not getting divided is there any config to change the size setting? can u please revisit my updated question with csv example

Comment: Hi Santhosh, I've removed the various tags that seemingly had nothing to do with either the original question (UDF on Databricks with RDD over parallelized Seq/List) nor your last two changes.  I suggest you go through the various existing documentation and stack entries that explain how partitions work as it's clear you are missing the basics right now.  Your current question change isn't clear either, but it's likely you have a single csv file, which means, by default a single partition and a single thread.  As you are seemingly very new at Spark, I'd also suggest using Datasets not RDD.